# Out of memory MySQL with 24GB Server

Tags: mysql, memory, innodb, my.cnf

I have come across an annoying problem.

I have made a system and now users are telling me that it is giving them the message:

Out of memory (Needed 268435427 bytes)

The entire database is 12MB in size and the query that is having the problem has ran fine for several months and isn't really that complex or large.

The database is innodb. My server has 24GB of ram so I seriously doubt it is actually out of memory.

my.cnf is as follows:

> key_buffer              = 8000M
>
> max_allowed_packet      = 1M
>
> table_cache             = 2048M
>
> sort_buffer_size        = 1M
>
> net_buffer_length       = 1024M
>
> read_buffer_size        = 1M
>
> read_rnd_buffer_size    = 24M
>
> innodb_log_file_size            = 5M
>
> innodb_log_buffer_size          = 8M
>
> innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1
>
> innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 50
>
> innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 1024M
>
> innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
>
> max_connections = 100
>
> query_cache_size = 128M
>
> query_cache_min_res_unit = 1024
>
> query_cache_limit = 16MB
>
> thread_cache_size = 100
>
> max_heap_table_size = 4096MB

When looking in windows task manager I am seeing 18.8GB available but with only 100MB free. It is Windows 2008 64bit Server, could this be the source of the problem?

---

Here is the query:

```
$currency     = '(SELECT currencies.symbol
                            FROM parts_trading, currencies
                            WHERE parts_trading.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                            AND parts_trading.sellingCurrency = currencies.id
                            LIMIT 1
                         )' ;

$amountDueSQL = '(
                         (SELECT SUM(quantity*(parts_trading.sellingNet
                                    +
                                    parts_trading.sellingVat))
                            FROM parts_trading
                            WHERE parts_trading.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                         )
                         +
                         (SELECT SUM(enquiries_custom_fees.feeAmountNet
                                    +
                                    enquiries_custom_fees.feeAmountVat)
                            FROM enquiries_custom_fees
                            WHERE enquiries_custom_fees.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                         )
                         )' ;
$amountPaidSQL = 'COALESCE(
                             (SELECT SUM(jobs_payments_advance.amount)
                                FROM jobs_payments_advance
                                WHERE jobs_payments_advance.jobRef = jobs.id
                             ),
                             0
                         )' ;

    $result = $dbh->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS jobs.id, jobs_states.state, jobs.creationDate, users.username,
                            entity_details.name, enquiries.id as enquiryId, pendingCancelation,
                            IF(entity_details.paymentTermsRef = 1, # Outer IF condition
                               IF($amountDueSQL-$amountPaidSQL = 0.00, # Inner IF condition
                                  CONCAT('Paid in full (', $currency, $amountDueSQL, ')') # Inner IF TRUE
                               , # End of inner IF TRUE
                                  IF($amountPaidSQL > 0,
                                     CONCAT('Part paid (', $currency, $amountPaidSQL, ')'),
                                     'Unpaid'
                                  )
                               ) # End of inner IF

                            , # End of TRUE for outer IF
                               (SELECT entity_payment_terms.term
                                    FROM entity_details, entity_payment_terms
                                    WHERE entity_details.paymentTermsRef
                                          =
                                          entity_payment_terms.id
                                    AND entity_details.id = enquiries.entityRef
                               ) # End of FALSE for outer IF
                            ) AS payState, enquiries.orderNumber,

                            IF((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM invoices_out, (SELECT * FROM invoices_out_reference GROUP BY jobRef) AS tb1
                             WHERE invoices_out.id = tb1.invoiceRef
                             AND tb1.jobRef = jobs.id) > 1,
                               'Part-invoiced',
                               (SELECT invoices_out.date
                                    FROM invoices_out, (SELECT * FROM invoices_out_reference GROUP BY jobRef) AS tb1
                             WHERE invoices_out.id = tb1.invoiceRef
                             AND tb1.jobRef = jobs.id)
                             ) AS invoicedDate,

                            enquiries.id AS enquiryId,

                            IF((SELECT COUNT(*)
                                    FROM invoices_out, (SELECT * FROM invoices_out_reference GROUP BY jobRef) AS tb1
                             WHERE invoices_out.id = tb1.invoiceRef
                             AND tb1.jobRef = jobs.id) > 1,
                               'Multiple invoices',
                               (SELECT invoices_out.id
                                    FROM invoices_out, (SELECT * FROM invoices_out_reference GROUP BY jobRef) AS tb1
                             WHERE invoices_out.id = tb1.invoiceRef
                             AND tb1.jobRef = jobs.id)
                             ) AS invoiceNumber,

                            # If the state is 0 (i.e. they have an account, if true find out their payment terms, if false, instead reference the payment state directly.
                            (SELECT MAX(etaDate) FROM parts_trading WHERE parts_trading.enquiryRef = enquiries.id) AS maxEtaDate,
                            (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(etaDate)) FROM parts_trading WHERE parts_trading.enquiryRef = enquiries.id) AS etaCounts, entity_credit_limits.creditLimit AS cLimit,
                            COALESCE((SELECT 
                                    SUM(qty*parts_trading_buying.buyingNet
                                    /
                                    (SELECT rateVsPound FROM currencies WHERE currencies.id = parts_trading_buying.buyingCurrency))
                                    FROM parts_trading_buying
                                    WHERE parts_trading_buying.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                                    ), 0
                                    ) AS nonInvoicedBuyingCosts,
                            COALESCE((SELECT 
                                    SUM(feeAmountNet/(SELECT rateVsPound FROM currencies WHERE currencies.id = parts_trading_buying.buyingCurrency))
                                    FROM parts_trading_buying_charges, parts_trading_buying 
                                    WHERE parts_trading_buying_charges.partRef = parts_trading_buying.id
                                    AND parts_trading_buying.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                                    ), 0
                                ) AS nonInvoicedBuyingFeeCosts,
                            (SELECT
                                SUM(quantity*parts_trading.sellingNet)
                                    /
                                    COALESCE(
                                        (SELECT invoices_out.rate
                                         FROM invoices_out, invoices_out_reference
                                         WHERE invoices_out.id = invoices_out_reference.invoiceRef
                                         AND invoices_out_reference.jobRef = jobs.id
                                         LIMIT 1),
                                        (SELECT rateVsPound
                                         FROM currencies
                                         WHERE currencies.id = parts_trading.sellingCurrency)
                                    )
                             FROM parts_trading
                             WHERE parts_trading.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                            ) AS sellingParts,
                            COALESCE((SELECT
                                    SUM(enquiries_custom_fees.feeAmountNet)
                                    /
                                    COALESCE(
                                        (SELECT rate
                                         FROM invoices_out, invoices_out_reference
                                         WHERE invoices_out.id = invoices_out_reference.invoiceRef
                                         AND invoices_out_reference.jobRef = jobs.id LIMIT 1),
                                        (SELECT rateVsPound
                                         FROM currencies
                                         WHERE currencies.id = parts_trading.sellingCurrency
                                         )
                                    )
                                    FROM enquiries_custom_fees, parts_trading
                                    WHERE enquiries_custom_fees.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                                    AND parts_trading.enquiryRef = enquiries.id), 0) AS sellingFees,
                            COALESCE((SELECT
                                    SUM(parts_shipping_out.shippingOutCost)
                                    FROM parts_shipping_out, parts_shipping_arrival_dates, parts_shipping_v2
                                    WHERE parts_shipping_out.arrivalsRef = parts_shipping_arrival_dates.id
                                    AND parts_shipping_arrival_dates.shippingRef = parts_shipping_v2.id
                                    AND parts_shipping_v2.jobRef = jobs.id
                                    ), 0
                                ) AS actualShippingOutFromEua,
                            (SELECT

                                SUM(quantity*parts_trading.sellingNet)
                                    /
                                    COALESCE(
                                        (SELECT invoices_out.rate
                                         FROM invoices_out, invoices_out_reference
                                         WHERE invoices_out.id = invoices_out_reference.invoiceRef
                                         AND invoices_out_reference.jobRef = jobs.id
                                         LIMIT 1),
                                        (SELECT rateVsPound
                                         FROM currencies
                                         WHERE currencies.id = parts_trading.sellingCurrency)
                                    )
                                +
                                COALESCE((SELECT
                                    SUM(enquiries_custom_fees.feeAmountNet)
                                    /
                                    COALESCE(
                                        (SELECT rate
                                         FROM invoices_out, invoices_out_reference
                                         WHERE invoices_out.id = invoices_out_reference.invoiceRef
                                         AND invoices_out_reference.jobRef = jobs.id LIMIT 1),
                                        (SELECT rateVsPound
                                         FROM currencies
                                         WHERE currencies.id = parts_trading.sellingCurrency
                                         )
                                    )
                                    FROM enquiries_custom_fees
                                    WHERE enquiries_custom_fees.enquiryRef = enquiries.id), 0)
                                -
                                COALESCE((SELECT 
                                    SUM(qty*parts_trading_buying.buyingNet
                                    /
                                    (SELECT rateVsPound FROM currencies WHERE currencies.id = parts_trading_buying.buyingCurrency))
                                    FROM parts_trading_buying
                                    WHERE parts_trading_buying.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                                    ), 0
                                    )
                                -
                                COALESCE((SELECT 
                                    SUM(feeAmountNet/(SELECT rateVsPound FROM currencies WHERE currencies.id = parts_trading_buying.buyingCurrency))
                                    FROM parts_trading_buying_charges, parts_trading_buying 
                                    WHERE parts_trading_buying_charges.partRef = parts_trading_buying.id
                                    AND parts_trading_buying.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                                    ), 0
                                )
                                -
                                COALESCE((SELECT
                                    SUM(parts_shipping_out.shippingOutCost)
                                    FROM parts_shipping_out, parts_shipping_arrival_dates, parts_shipping_v2
                                    WHERE parts_shipping_out.arrivalsRef = parts_shipping_arrival_dates.id
                                    AND parts_shipping_arrival_dates.shippingRef = parts_shipping_v2.id
                                    AND parts_shipping_v2.jobRef = jobs.id
                                    ), 0
                                )
                                FROM parts_trading, parts_trading_buying
                                WHERE parts_trading.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                                AND parts_trading_buying.counterpartRef = parts_trading.id
                            ) AS margin
                            FROM jobs,
                            jobs_states, enquiries, users, jobs_payment_status, entity_details
                            LEFT JOIN entity_credit_limits ON entity_details.id = entity_credit_limits.entityRef
                            WHERE jobs.stateRef = jobs_states.id
                            AND IF(paymentStateRef = 0, 1, (jobs_payment_status.id = jobs.paymentStateRef))
                            # ^ If true it causes a result for each payment state (i.e. 3), so we group on state below, shouldn't cause probs.
                            AND jobs.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                            AND enquiries.entityRef = entity_details.id
                            AND users.id = enquiries.traderRef
                            AND enquiries.traderRef = ?
                                LIMIT ?, ?") ;
```

If I try setting PHP execution memory above 3.5GB Apache wont start (I'm using xampp). I must be using a 32-bit version of PHP? This is the same for the INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_SIZE, which I would like to be 14GB, but mysql won't start if I do that.

Comment: Whats the query? can you also give relevant tables + indexes..

Comment: Indexes take a lot of space, if you have indexes defined on  many columns, it may cause problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is a database related problem becouse this kind of error (Out of memory (Needed 268435427 bytes)) most of the time throwed by PHP (infinite loop or something similar is maybe the problem).

Comment: Even though I'm running the query separately in PHPMyAdmin? I still get the error.

Comment: Try running it directly with mysql. Maybe the PHP's execution memory limit is to low.

Answer (score 0):

Now (for two minutes of your time) you can use MySQLCalculator.com to see basic RAM footprint.
If all the per connection RAM entries in configuration had a leading # you would run fine, actually much better.  With the line of read_rnd_buffer_size = 24M rather than the default of 256K you are reading 96 X more index information than necessary.